# jQuery - How to make a div follow a cursor... within its center

Tags: javascript, jquery

So this is what I got.

```
 <div class="box"></div>
```

---

```
 .box {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background: yellow;
 }
```

---

```
 $(document).bind('mousemove', function(e){
 $('.box').css({
 top: e.pageY
 left:  e.pageX,
 });
 });
```

It works. The box follow the cursor. Problem is it follow the EDGE of the cursor. ie, the cursor holds the top left corner of the box.
I want it to hold the center of the box, or another point that's not the edge. Any ideas how to do that?

Sorry if this dumb. I'm good enough with HTML/CSS but just starting with javascript and jQuery.

Comment: there is an error on your line of codes there should be a comma after the pageY

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this code instead

```
 $(document).bind('mousemove', function(e){
   $('.box').css({
     top: e.pageY - $(".box").height()/2, // just minus by half the height
     left:  e.pageX - $(".box").width()/2 // just minus by half the width
   });
 });
```

Comment: Is there any chance to keep the element's position (.box) even while scrolling? Because, whenever scrolling is necessary, the element (.box) moves away from the cursor position. https://jsfiddle.net/huydtLmp/3/

Comment: @didi A simple way is to set the css position to fixed instead of absolute.